# Change HTML DropDown Default Value with a MySQL value

Tags: php, forms

I'm working on a profile page, where a registered user can update their information. Because the user has already submitted their information, I would like their information from the database to populate my HTML form.

Within PHP, I'm creating the HTML form with the values filled in. However, I've tried creating an IF statement to determine whether an option is selected as the default value. Right now, my website is giving me a default value of the last option, Undeclared. Therefore, I'm not sure if all IF statements are evaluation as true, or if it is simply skipping to selected=selected.

Here is my HTML, which is currently embedded with PHP(`<?php ?>`):

```
<?php

// Connect to MySQL
$db = mysql_connect("", "xxx", "xxx");

if (!$db)
{
    exit("Error - Could not connect to MySQL");
}

$er = mysql_select_db("cs329e_fall11_nemo008", $db);

if (!$er)
{
    exit("Error - Could not select the database");
}

$query = "SELECT *
FROM tblMembers
WHERE Username = 'fzr11017' ";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result)
{
    print("Error - The query could not be executed");
    $error = mysql_error();
    print("<p>:" . $error . "</p>");
    exit;
}

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

print <<<FORM

<form id="frmRegister" action="update.php" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate()" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><br /></th>
        <td><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Username:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Username" maxlength="10" value=$row[Username] readonly="readonly"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">First Name:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" value=$row[FirstName] readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Last Name:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="LastName" value=$row[LastName] readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Email Address:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Email" value=$row[Email] /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Phone Number:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Phone" maxlength="10" value=$row[Phone] /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Year:</th>
        <td>
            <select name="Year" >
                <option if(strcmp($row[Year], 'Freshman') == 0){ selected="selected"} >Freshman</option>
                <option if(strcmp($row[Year], 'Sophomore') == 0){ selected="selected"} >Sophomore</option>
                <option if(strcmp($row[Year], 'Junior') == 0){ selected="selected"} >Junior</option>
                <option if(strcmp($row[Year], 'Senior') == 0){ selected="selected"} >Senior</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Primary Major:</th>
        <td>
            <select name="Major">
                <option if($row[Major] == Accounting){ selected="selected"}>Accounting</option>
                <option if($row[Major] == Business Honors Program){ selected="selected"}>Business Honors Program</option>
                <option if($row[Major] == Engineering Route to Business){ selected="selected"}>Engineering Route to Business</option>
                <option if($row[Major] == Finance){ selected="selected"}>Finance</option>
                <option if($row[Major] == International Business){ selected="selected"}>International Business</option>
                <option if($row[Major] == Management){ selected="selected"}>Management</option>
                <option if($row[Major] == Management Information Systems){ selected="selected"}>Management Information Systems</option>
                <option if($row[Major] == Marketing){ selected="selected"}>Marketing</option>
                <option if($row[Major] == MPA){ selected="selected"}>MPA</option>
                <option if($row[Major] == Supply Chain Management){ selected="selected"}>Supply Chain Management</option>
                <option if($row[Major] == Undeclared){ selected="selected"}>Undeclared</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><br /></th>
        <td><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
FORM;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing any  tags in your code, which means that nothing is being processed. Something more along the lines of this should be used:

```
<option <?php if($row["Major"] == "Accounting"){ echo "selected"; } ?>>Accounting</option>
```

Comment: A slight variant of my solution

Comment: Currently, the whole form is under PHP tags, so that's why my variable $row[Major] is being called from MYSQL. Do I need to put nested PHP tags for the IF statement to work?

Comment: HTML and PHP are two entirely different domains. You must not place HTML within PHP tags, nor vice versa.

Comment: That makes sense. What I've done is started using PHP and did print <<<FORM, followed with my multiple lines of a form in HTML. I assumed I could extract the MySQL value and set it to the value of the drop down as I did for HTML textboxes. I've updated the code above to describe what I've been doing.

Comment: Is this solution even feasible in this manner with the drop downs as it was with the text?

Answer (score 2):

You've mixed HTML and PHP without declaring PHP tags and you've also used 'selected' as an attribute...

```
<select name="Major">
    <option <?php echo ($row['Major'] == "Accounting") ? " selected" : ""; ?>>Accounting</option>

    ....

</select>
```

I've done the first one, but you can follow the same pattern

Answer (score 2):

That code looks like it could use a [towel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
<select name="Major">
<?php
  $options = array(
      'Accounting'
    , 'Business Honors Program'
    , 'Engineering Route to Business'
    , 'Finance'
    , 'International Business'
    , 'Management'
    , 'Management Information Systems'
    , 'Marketing'
    , 'MPA'
    , 'Supply Chain Management'
    , 'Undeclared'
  );

  foreach( $options as $option )
  {
    printf(
      "<option%s>%s</option>\n"
        , ($row['Major'] == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '')
        , htmlentities($option)
    );
  }
?>
</select>
```

You might find some of this reading useful to help explain some of the concepts used above:

- [arrays](http://php.net/arrays)
- [`foreach` loop](http://php.net/foreach)
- [ternary operator (`?:`)](http://php.net/operators.comparison#language.operators.comparison.ternary)
- [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf)
- [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities)