# HTML select default value from database

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add an HTML "`select dropdown list`" for gender. However I want the default value from the database with php framework. Can I do that?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague in the sense that the context is ambiguous... can you provide some of your code for more insight?

Comment: did you even search SO before posting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299928/change-html-dropdown-default-value-with-a-mysql-value  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293939/select-dropdown-default-value or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656107/get-data-from-database-to-select-a-default-value-for-the-drop-down-box plus many more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915584/is-it-possible-to-query-a-mysql-database-from-a-field-selected-from-dropdown-men

Comment: I hope this post answers your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124911/select-option-default-based-on-database-variable

Comment: select name="Sex">
  <option>MALE</option>
  <option>FEMALE</option>
</select>

Comment: `<select name="Sex"> <option<?php if($dbValue == "MALE") echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>MALE</option> <option<?php if($dbValue == "FEMALE") echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>FEMALE</option> </select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
$default_gender = getDefaultGenderValueFromDB;
<select name="genderSelected">
<option value="m"<?php echo ($default_gender == 'm')? selected:'';?>>Male</option>
<option value="f"<?php echo ($default_gender== 'f')? selected:'';?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

Valid code snippet:

```
<?php $default_gender = 'm'; ?>

<select name="genderSelected">
<option value="m" <?php echo ($default_gender == 'm')? 'selected="selected"':'';?>>Male</option>
<option value="f" <?php echo ($default_gender == 'f')? 'selected="selected"':'';?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I've tried this but it the default value is male or whatever that is typed first.

Comment: OK I posted pseudo code - in other words not code that would work but rather an basic outline of how to code. I have changed my answer to include working, valid code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td>Sex: </td> <td>  <select name="Sex">
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "Select sex from personaltab where empno='$emplno'");
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     $gender =$rows['sex'];
        echo "<option if($gender == 'FEMALE') { selected='selected'} value='FEMALE'>FEMALE</option>";
        echo "<option value='MALE' if($gender == 'MALE') { selected='selected' }>MALE</option>";




    ?>
   </select> </td></tr>
```

dont use if else..